# Como girar hoja de pdf Automaticamente en php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php5

Estoy realizando un reporte en php con fpdf y deseo girar la hoja con el fin de añadir mas campos.

Como puedo hacer para que cuando se genere automáticamente haga el giro y me lo muestre de forma horizontal?

Answer (score 1):

Si estas utilizando el constructor deberias colocarlo en los parametros de la siguiente manera:

```
FPDF([string orientación [, string unidad [, mixed formato]]);
```

o de esta manera:

```
$pdf=new FPDF('P', 'mm', '300, 200');
```

ya que asi es de manera vertical:

```
$pdf=new PDF('P', 'mm', '200, 300');
```

Answer (score 0):

YO LO HAGO ASI Y ME FUNCIONA:

$pdf=new FPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4');  PARA VERTIVAL

$pdf=new FPDF('L', 'mm', 'A4');  PARA HORIZONTAL

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Asumo que "P" es por _portrait_ y "L" por _landscape_... Lee [answer].